# Single Responsibility Principal and Repository or Application Service classes

Tags: design-patterns, repository, crud, single-responsibility-principle, conceptual

As **SRP** said :

> a class or module should have one, and only one, reason to change

I have some repository classes for each type of my entities(each type, one repository) that implement `CRUD` operations.
So, these type of repository classes seems that have more than one reason to change, e.g each query conditions may change or etc.

This case occur for application services classes also, I think.

My questions are:

- Does cause using this type of repository or application service classes, violate SRP?
- If it violate, How can i, handle this problem?

Comment: What is the more than one reason that you can think of?

Comment: @Fendy: e.g 1-adding some validations to some methods, 2-change some queries

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, a SOLID purist would argue that, yes, constantly modifying a repository to add new methods representing various queries would violate the SRP. However, I think this approach to repository design has become reasonably accepted.

With respect to querying alone, you can use the Specification pattern to outline your queries. If you modify your repositories to accept a specification then they should become closed to modification with regard to developing new queries.

Comment: Thanks, what about application service classes?

Comment: I don't really know an application service class is. Can you give an example?

Comment: Application service used by external consumers to talk to my system (think Web Services). If consumers need access to CRUD operations, they would be exposed here. it work such as Facade.